# Laravel 4 javascript ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I performed and Ajax request when a button is being clicked, to make a get request and update a div,but my page doesn't seem to update at all.but using the debugging tools i realised that:

```
it gives error: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

But when i save my xmlhttp.responseText to a variable and i alert it alert this:

```
<div>

This is a new Ajax Message !! Thanks
</div>
```

which is the content of msg.blage.php that am requesting for.Though am new to using ajax and laravel.

Below here is the code:

register.blade.php

```
<button id="btn" onclick="makerequest('{{route('msg')}}','succesMessage')">Update!!</button>
<div id="successMessage"></div>
```

msg.blade.php

```
<div>
This is a new Ajax Message !! Thanks
</div>
```

script.js

```
function makerequest(serverPage, objID) {
var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
  alert(data);
obj.innerHTML=data;
}
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

routes.js

```
Route::get('/msg',['as' => 'msg', 'uses' => 'HomeController@msg']);
```

HomeContoller.php

```
public function msg()
    {
        return View::make('msg');
    }
```

The error shows on line   "sortable.js:14";

and that i think is the second each()

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id="btn" onclick="makerequest('{{route('msg')}}','succesMessage')">Update!!</button>
<div id="successMessage"></div>
```

You have a typo in the first line, `succesMessage` instead of `successMessage`. It's trying and failing to find an element with the ID `succesMessage` as a result.

Comment: Thanks very much!! Can't belive its just that.